# Ford Fiesta Mk6 heater blower fan motor resistor location?

Tags: ford, fiesta, heater-blower

Does anyone know the exact location of the heater blower fan motor resistor on the Ford Fiesta Mk6 (JH1/HHJB1) ? A picture will help a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully not a bad assumption, but I'm assuming you're vehicle is right hand drive (European). That said, to get to your resistor pack, there is a kick panel which has to be removed which is against the center console in the passenger footwell. The panel should be fairly easy to remove.once removed, locate the blower housing, which is towards the front of the car. It will have a cross hatch looking design on it and is made of dark grey plastic. Reaching your hand around between the blower housing and the firewall, you'll find a plug which has several wires attached to it. The connector should be light grey in color and is fairly square in nature. Attached to that is your resistor pack.

[Here is a video of a guy replacing the resistor pack](http://youtu.be/5IV_5ipXqHI), so should give you exact location.

Comment: @paulster2 The video is for the Mk7 fiesta. I found on other forums users saying that it's under the steering wheel, to the left near the clutch. But it doesn't make any sense to me.

This should be the resistor: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/FORD-FIESTA-MK7-1-4-TDCI-68-DIESEL-2008-2013-HEATER-BLOWER-FAN-RESISTOR-/151966694763?hash=item2361ebbd6b:g:U78AAOSwL7VWq0RX

 I am only unsure of it's location/

Comment: That's the one for the Mk7 ... I thought yours is a Mk6? Maybe it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: I will have to start unscrewing panels :). Thanks for the help.

Comment: It should be relatively in the same place as the one in the video. I would bet it may even be the same exact HVAC box between the two. It has to be in the HVAC box someplace so that air will flow over it which allows it to cool.

Answer (score 2):

here is a clear picture underthe dash of a right hand drive fiesta. it may be the same for older fiestas but this one is a 2011

[image: blower resistor location]

Answer (score 1):

It's on the drivers side, just above the pedals, a nightmare to get at. Get a telescopic mirror with lights. This helps big time. I didn't remove any panelling. Lay the drivers seat all the way back lie upside down with your head in the footwell, it can be done. Once I remembered I had the telescopic mirror it only took about 15 mins. This is for a Ford Fiesta mk6 2007 UK version.